# How to add DarkMode to Navigator in App.js

Tags: react-native, expo, ios-darkmode, themeprovider

I have to add DarkMode switch to one of the Screen which applies to all the screen in  React Native IOS App.

Below is the App.js where I wrap my main navigator inside ThemeProvider

```
import React from 'react';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import {createStore, combineReducers,applyMiddleware} from 'redux';
import ReduxThunk from 'redux-thunk';
import authReducer from './store/reducers/auth';
import deviceReducer from './store/reducers/device';
import FR_Navigator from './navigation/FR_Navigator';
import downloadReducer from './store/reducers/download';
import { RootSiblingParent } from 'react-native-root-siblings';
import { ThemeProvider} from './theme/theme-context';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
 auth: authReducer,
 download:downloadReducer,
 device:deviceReducer
 });

 const store = createStore(rootReducer,applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk));

 export default class App extends React.Component {
 render() {
 return (   
  <Provider store={store}>
     <ThemeProvider>
       <FR_Navigator />
     </ThemeProvider>
  </Provider>
   );
 }
 }
```

Below is the FRNavigator which has Settings Page which sets DarkMode.

FRNavigator.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { View,StyleSheet,SafeAreaView,Button,ScrollView,Text} from 'react-native';
import { createSwitchNavigator,createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import {createStackNavigator,StackViewTransitionConfigs} from 'react-navigation- 
 stack';
import MainPage from '../screens/FaceRecog/MainPage';
import UploadPage from '../screens/FaceRecog/UploadPage';
import { createDrawerNavigator,DrawerItems} from 'react-navigation-drawer';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
import DownloadPage from '../screens/FaceRecog/DownloadPage';
import RateUsScreen from '../screens/FaceRecog/RateUsScreen';
import ForgotPasswordScreen from '../screens/UI/ForgotPasswordScreen';
import ImageBrowserScreen from '../screens/FaceRecog/ImageBrowserScreen';
import LoginScreen from '../screens/UI/LoginScreen';
import RegisterScreen from '../screens/UI/Register';
import AddDevicePage from '../screens/FaceRecog/AddDevicePage';
import LogoutComponent from '../components/FaceRecog/LogoutComponent'
import DrawerHeader from '../components/FaceRecog/DrawerHeader';
import CommunicateComponent from '../components/FaceRecog/CommunicateComponent';
import ManageDevice from '../screens/FaceRecog/ManageDevicePage';
import Register from '../screens/UI/Register';
import Settings from '../screens/FaceRecog/Settings';

 const AuthNavigator = createStackNavigator(
 {
 Login:
 {
 screen:LoginScreen,
 navigationOptions: {
  headerShown: false,
 }
 },
 SignUp:
 {
 screen:Register
 },
 ForgotPasswordPage:
{
 screen:ForgotPasswordScreen,
 navigationOptions: {
  headerShown: true,
}
}
},
);

const MainPageNavigator = createStackNavigator({
Home:MainPage,
AddDevice:AddDevicePage,
Upload:UploadPage,
ImagePicker:ImageBrowserScreen,
ManageDev:ManageDevice,
Setting:
  {
    screen:Settings,
    transitionConfig: () => StackViewTransitionConfigs.SlideFromRightIOS,
  },
  
   RateUs:RateUsScreen,
  })
  const DrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator(
 {    
 Home:
{
  screen:MainPageNavigator,
  navigationOptions:{
    drawerIcon:(
      <Icon
      name='md-home-sharp' size={25}  color='grey'/>
    )
  }
},

Download:
{
  screen:DownloadPage,
  navigationOptions:{
    drawerIcon:(
      <Icon
      name='md-download'
      type='ionicons' size={25} color='grey'onPress={ () => {
     
    }}/>
  
    )
  }
},
Exit:
{
  screen:Register,
  navigationOptions:{
    drawerIcon:(
      <Icon
      name='exit-outline'
      type='ionicons' size={25} color='grey' onPress={ () => {
      
    }}/>
  
    )
  }
} 
},

{
 contentOptions:{
activeTintColor: '#e91e63',

},   
contentComponent: (props) =>
 <ScrollView>
  <SafeAreaView style={{flex:1}} forceInset={{ top: 'always', horizontal: 'never', 
     height:180 }}>
    <View style={{width:'100%', backgroundColor: 'white', }}> 
      <DrawerHeader />
    </View>
    <DrawerItems {...props} />
    <LogoutComponent />
    <View
                    style={{
                    borderBottomColor: 'grey',
                    borderBottomWidth: 1

                }}/> 
                <View style={styles.communicateview}>
    <Text style={styles.communicatetext}>Communicate</Text>
    <CommunicateComponent {...props}/>
    </View>
  </SafeAreaView>
  </ScrollView>,
   },
   );


  const MainNavigator = createSwitchNavigator({
  Auth: AuthNavigator,
  App:DrawerNavigator
  });

   const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  communicatetext:{
   fontWeight:'800',
   color:'grey'
  },
  communicateview:{
    top:'3%',
    left:'3%'
  }
  })

  export default createAppContainer(MainNavigator);
```

Below is the Settings Page where I have added Toggle button to set DarkMode:
Settings.js

```
import React,{useState,useContext} from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet ,Text,Switch,StatusBar,TouchableOpacity,Button} from 
 'react-native';
import { HeaderButtons, Item } from 'react-navigation-header-buttons';
import HeaderButton from '../../components/UI/HeaderButton'; 
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Entypo';
import { ThemeContext } from '../../theme/theme-context';

const Settings = props => {
 const { dark, theme, toggle } = useContext(ThemeContext);

 return <View  style={styles.container}>
<View style={styles.appsettingstextview}>
<Text style={styles.appsettingstext}>App Settings </Text>

<View style={styles.box}>
  <View style={{right:80}}>
    <Icon name='adjust' type='entypo' size={40}  color='#00008B'/>
 </View>
   <View style={{right:70}}><Text style={{fontWeight:'bold'}}>Dark Mode</Text></View>
    <View style={{left:80}}>
      <Switch
     trackColor={{ false: "#767577", true: "#ccc" }}
     thumbColor={dark ? "#fff" : "#f4f3f4"}
     onChange={toggle} value = {dark} />
   </View>
  </View>
</View> 
</View>
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container:{
flex:1,paddingTop:40,paddingLeft:20,
paddingBottom: 60
},
apppermissiontextview:{
},
appsettingstext:{
fontSize:17,
color:'#0437F2',
fontWeight:'bold'
},
apppermissiontextview:{
top:'5%',
},
apppermissiontext:{
fontSize:17,
color:'#0437F2',
fontWeight:'bold'
},
box: {
shadowColor: 'rgba(0,0,0, .4)', // IOS
shadowOffset: { height: 1, width: 1 },
shadowOpacity: 1, // IOS
shadowRadius: 1, //IOS
backgroundColor: '#fff',
elevation: 2, // Android
height: 80,
width:380,
borderRadius: 5,
marginVertical: 40,
backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF",
alignItems: "center",
justifyContent: "center",
flexDirection: 'row',
},
text: {
fontSize: 14,
fontWeight: "bold",
margin: 8,
color: "#000",
textAlign: "center"
}
});

Settings.navigationOptions = navData =>{
return{
headerTitle: 'Settings',
headerTitleStyle:{
   color:'white',
   
},
headerTitleAlign:"left",
headerStyle: {
  backgroundColor: '#0437F2',
  
},
headerLeft: () =>
  <HeaderButtons HeaderButtonComponent={HeaderButton}>
    <Item
      //title="Menu"
      iconName={'chevron-back-outline'}
      onPress={() => {
        //navData.navigation.toggleDrawer();
       navData.navigation.navigate('Home');
      }}
    />
  </HeaderButtons>
 }
 };
 export default Settings;
```

If I run the above program, when I toggle the Switch, nothing happens.Can anyone say how to add the Settings.js Page to work with FRNavigator to support darkmode toggle switch.Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

I added darkmode style as style={[styles.box,{ backgroundColor: theme.backgroundColor }]}> to the View in the Settings Page and I could get switch between dark and light theme.Below is the Settings code changes I made :

Settings.js:

```
import React,{useState,useContext} from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet 
,Text,Switch,StatusBar,TouchableOpacity,Button} from 'react-native';
import { HeaderButtons, Item } from 'react-navigation-header-buttons';
import HeaderButton from '../../components/UI/HeaderButton'; 
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Entypo';
import { ThemeContext } from '../../theme/theme-context';

const Settings = () => {
const { dark, theme, toggle } = useContext(ThemeContext);


 return <View  style={styles.container}>
 <View style={styles.appsettingstextview}>
 <Text style={styles.appsettingstext}>App Settings </Text>
 <View style={[styles.box,{ backgroundColor: theme.backgroundColor }]}>
   <View style={{right:80}}><Icon
  name='adjust'
  type='entypo' size={40}  color='#00008B'/>
 </View>
 <View style={{right:70}}><Text style={[styles.darkmodetext, 
 {color:theme.color}]}>Dark Mode</Text></View>
 <View style = {styles.containerSwitch}>
   <Switch
     trackColor={{ false: "#ccc", true: "#d43790" }}
     thumbColor={dark ? "#f5dd4b" : "#f4f3f4"}
     ios_backgroundColor="#3e3e3e"
     onChange={toggle} value = {dark} />
  </View>
  </View>
    </View>
   </View>
   };

    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container:{
    flex:1,paddingTop:40,paddingLeft:20,
    paddingBottom: 60
    },


    appsettingstext:{
    fontSize:17,
    color:'#0437F2',
    fontWeight:'bold'
    },

    darkmodetext:{
    fontWeight:'bold',
    fontSize:18
    },
   
   box: {
   shadowColor: 'rgba(0,0,0, .4)', // IOS
   shadowOffset: { height: 1, width: 1 },
   shadowOpacity: 1, // IOS
   shadowRadius: 1, //IOS
   backgroundColor: '#fff',
   elevation: 2, // Android
   height: 80,
   width:380,
   borderRadius: 5,
   marginVertical: 40,
   backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF",
   alignItems: "center",
   justifyContent: "center",
   flexDirection: 'row',
   bottom:'7%'
   },
   text: {
   fontSize: 14,
   fontWeight: "bold",
   margin: 8,
    color: "#000",
   textAlign: "center"
   },
   containerSwitch:{
   marginBottom:50,
     top:'6%',
   left:'110%'
   }
   });

   Settings.navigationOptions = navData =>{
   return{
   headerTitle: 'Settings',
   headerTitleStyle:{
   color:'white',
   
},
headerTitleAlign:"left",
headerStyle: {
  backgroundColor: '#0437F2',
  
},
headerLeft: () =>
  <HeaderButtons HeaderButtonComponent={HeaderButton}>
    <Item
      //title="Menu"
      iconName={'chevron-back-outline'}
      onPress={() => {
        //navData.navigation.toggleDrawer();
       navData.navigation.navigate('Home');
      }}
    />
  </HeaderButtons>
  }

  };
  export default Settings;
```